# Documenting with doxygen: put details on top

Tags: documentation, customization, doxygen

I'm using doxygen for a documentation of an Android project. I know doxygen since years. But now I have the problem that I want the details of my class like in javadoc at the top and not at the bottom.

After a short Google search I found the option `DETAILS_AT_TOP` which would just do what I want but unfortunately this option was removed. So the new method is to use a so called [`DoxygenLayout.xml`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_layout_file), but where is the documentation how that file should look like? In the documentation are only some attributes explained. **Where is the original `DoxygenLayout.xml` which I can modify as I need it?**

I had also the same problem with the `HTML_FOOTER` it is not documented how the original file looks like.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After doing some more research with the command line options I found this:

> 4) Use doxygen to generate a template file controlling the layout of
>   the    generated documentation:
>       doxygen -l layoutFileName.xml

So I got my `DoxygenLayout.xml` with `doxygen -l`. I just modyfied the order of the details and deactivated the brief version:

```xml
<doxygenlayout version="1.0">
  <!-- Generated by doxygen 1.8.5 -->
  <!-- Navigation index tabs for HTML output -->
  <navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespacelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="classlist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title=""/> 
      <tab type="hierarchy" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classmembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="filelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>  
  </navindex>

  <!-- Layout definition for a class page -->
  <class>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <includes visible="$SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES"/>
    <inheritancegraph visible="$CLASS_GRAPH"/>
    <collaborationgraph visible="$COLLABORATION_GRAPH"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestedclasses visible="yes" title=""/>
      <publictypes title=""/>
      <services title=""/>
      <interfaces title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicmethods title=""/>
      <publicstaticmethods title=""/>
      <publicattributes title=""/>
      <publicstaticattributes title=""/>
      <protectedtypes title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <protectedmethods title=""/>
      <protectedstaticmethods title=""/>
      <protectedattributes title=""/>
      <protectedstaticattributes title=""/>
      <packagetypes title=""/>
      <packagemethods title=""/>
      <packagestaticmethods title=""/>
      <packageattributes title=""/>
      <packagestaticattributes title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <privatetypes title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <privatemethods title=""/>
      <privatestaticmethods title=""/>
      <privateattributes title=""/>
      <privatestaticattributes title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
      <related title="" subtitle=""/>
      <membergroups visible="yes"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <services title=""/>
      <interfaces title=""/>
      <constructors title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <related title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <allmemberslink visible="yes"/>
    <usedfiles visible="$SHOW_USED_FILES"/>
    <authorsection visible="yes"/>
  </class>

  <!-- Layout definition for a namespace page -->
  <namespace>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestednamespaces visible="yes" title=""/>
      <constantgroups visible="yes" title=""/>
      <classes visible="yes" title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="yes"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection visible="yes"/>
  </namespace>

  <!-- Layout definition for a file page -->
  <file>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <includes visible="$SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES"/>
    <includegraph visible="$INCLUDE_GRAPH"/>
    <includedbygraph visible="$INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH"/>
    <sourcelink visible="yes"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <classes visible="yes" title=""/>
      <namespaces visible="yes" title=""/>
      <constantgroups visible="yes" title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="yes"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection/>
  </file>

  <!-- Layout definition for a group page -->
  <group>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <groupgraph visible="$GROUP_GRAPHS"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestedgroups visible="yes" title=""/>
      <dirs visible="yes" title=""/>
      <files visible="yes" title=""/>
      <namespaces visible="yes" title=""/>
      <classes visible="yes" title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <enumvalues title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="yes"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <memberdef>
      <pagedocs/>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <enumvalues title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection visible="yes"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Layout definition for a directory page -->
  <directory>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <directorygraph visible="yes"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <dirs visible="yes"/>
      <files visible="yes"/>
    </memberdecl>
  </directory>
</doxygenlayout>
```

After a short review of the output I desiced to remove the headline with this small css:

```css
a + h2.groupheader {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the real answer - mine's just a supplementary one.

Comment: I found documentation for this here: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does the CSS get rid of the "Detailed Description" header. I'm not too familiar with it, is what you've given all that is required in a css file, and can you possibly explain where to put the css file?

Comment: I used doxygen the last time in January, I guess next week I will use it for documentation something then I can look into the details. For now, in the doxygen file is a field for supplying a custom CSS file just enter there the file name and it will be added.

Comment: Thanks. Found it now in the docs, I was searching for "css". "Stylesheet" is a better term to search for.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using this for ai-statefultask (e.g. https://carlowood.github.io/ai-statefultask/classAIThreadPool.html). The css that I'm using is: a#details + h2.groupheader {
  display:none;
}
(using the '#details' part seemed more safe) and
div.textblock {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #879ECB;
  width: 100%;
} to draw a line before the #include line below the detailed description.

Answer (score 7):

For `HTML_FOOTER` (and header & CSS) there is a similar command to generate a local copy of the default Doxygen HTML.  You can then use the **HTML_*** doxyfile settings to point to them.

> doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen.css

Details for this are on [this page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) of the online manual.

Comment: @danorton OP found it useful (read comments above) and I think that's more important than pedantic sniping.

Comment: I'm sorry that you see it as "sniping", as I mean nothing personal by it. Whether the OP felt is was useful does not change the OP's question, which this does not answer. If the OP changes the question in such a manner that this answers it, I'll reconsider.

Comment: @danorton Do you not see it is an answer to the OP's second, albeit implied, question: "I had also the same problem with the HTML_FOOTER..." ?